# Display [Object] [Object] in *ngfor Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I'm making a request to a Controller from angular, that's working because I've checked the http request and the response contains a collection of objects with their properties. The problem is to display those object in the html view using `*ngfor`...I'm using a service called JobsService:

```
@Injectable()
export class JobsService {
    private _jobsUrl = 'http://localhost:59164/jobs';
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getJobs(): Observable<Job[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._jobsUrl).map((response: Response) => <Job>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error')
    }
}
```

This is the JobsComponent class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JobsService } from './jobs.service';
import { Job } from './job';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './tsScripts/jobs/jobs.component.html',
    providers: [JobsService]
})

export class JobsComponent implements OnInit {
    jobs: Job[] = [];
    errorMessage: string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("in OnInit");     
        this._jobsService.getJobs().subscribe(jobs => this.jobs = jobs, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }  

    constructor(private _jobsService: JobsService) {

    }
}
```

This is the html page:

```
<table class="table"> <!--*ngIf="jobs && jobs.length"-->
    <tr *ngFor="let job of jobs">
        <td>{{job.Title}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are
>   allowed

I think is complaining because is expecting an array and is just getting an object, if that is the case how could I solve it? I thought the variable `jobs` in my component was an array of `Job` class...

Just in case this is the `Job` class:

```
export class Job {
    aut_id: number;
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    AuthorEmail: string;
    Company: string;
    Location: string;
    TypeOfJob: string;
    Salary: number;
    CandidateExperience: string;
    CandidateEducation: string;
    Language: string;
    Approved: string;
}
```

And this is the C# controller:

```
  public JsonResult Index()
        {
            AzureStorageHelper az = new AzureStorageHelper();
            var totalJobs = az.GetJobs();
            var result = totalJobs.Where(j => string.Equals(j.Approved, "Approved", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            var test = result.ToList();
            return Json(new { data = test }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: if you do a console.log into this._jobsService.getJobs().subscribe(jobs => console.log(jobs)) you have an arry of Jobs in the console or array of objects?

Comment: @mickaelw array of objects..

Comment: I think your mapping in the service isn't correct

Comment: What do you get when you console.log the Json response? Like you said, it seems to be returning just an object and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

To cast the response, it's preferable to use an interface and to map the result to own class.

I propose you this code:

```
@Injectable()
export class JobsService {
  private _jobsUrl = 'http://localhost:59164/jobs';
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getJobs(): Observable<Job[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._jobsUrl).map(response => response.json().map(job => this.mapToJob(job)))
      .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error')
  }

  private mapToJob(job: JobDTO): Job {
    return new Job(
      +job.aut_id,
      job.Title,
      job.Description,
      job.AuthorEmail,
      job.Company,
      job.Location,
      job.TypeOfJob,
      +job.Salary,
      job.CandidateExperience,
      job.CandidateEducation,
      job.Language,
      job.Approved
    )
  }

}

export class Job{
  aut_id: number;
  Title: string;
  Description: string;
  AuthorEmail: string;
  Company: string;
  Location: string;
  TypeOfJob: string;
  Salary: number;
  CandidateExperience: string;
  CandidateEducation: string;
  Language: string;
  Approved: string;
}


export interface JobDTO{
  aut_id: number;
  Title: string;
  Description: string;
  AuthorEmail: string;
  Company: string;
  Location: string;
  TypeOfJob: string;
  Salary: number;
  CandidateExperience: string;
  CandidateEducation: string;
  Language: string;
  Approved: string;
}
```

To cast API I use an interface it's called a DTO (Data Transfer Object) which help to build the job know by my project.

For the moment, the DTO and the class have same fields, but it's possible that's different.

Notice another things: `response.json().map(job => this.mapToJob(job))` because I think you JSON return an array? So, I map it to have an array of Jobs.

Comment: I copied and pasted this code but I'm getting an error in the `mapToJob()` method when creating the new `Job` instance. The error is: `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`. I think is related with the parameter that is being passed to that method when is being called...

Comment: @AlexGH can you share a screenshot of the new service?

Comment: @michaelw I've upload an screenshot of the new error, I'm sorry I didn't reply you before I had to work on different stuff these days, thanks

Comment: @AlexGH can you try to add + before job.aut_id and job.Salary? Like in my updated answer

Comment: @michaelw still same error.. I will let you know if I find out about this

Comment: @AlexGH it's strange VS said you parameters don't match... all types are equals?

Comment: @michaelw doing this in my component worked: `this._jobsService.getJobs().subscribe((data: Job[]) => {
            this.jobs = data['data'];  });`  I took a look to the `Json` returned and it was `data: {[attributes and values...]}` so I included the Key 'data' to convert to the specific `Job` object in `js`. Thanks!